# Could not find a method in the activity class android.view.ContextThemeWrapper for onClick handler

Tags: java, android, onclick

I have this problem. I am using two dialog well, one dialog on a dialog, but the second dialog crash when try to search the method. Somebody can help me?

**XML: login-email**

```
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/forgot_password_email"
    android:id="@+id/login_email_tvForgetPassword"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:onClick="openForgetPasswordSend"/>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public void openForgetPasswordSend(View view){
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    loginforgetpasswordDialogFragment.show(fragmentManager,"Forget Pass");
}
```

**LoginForgetPassword.java**

```
public class LoginForgetPassword extends DialogFragment{

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog (Bundle savedInstanceState){

        // 1. Instantiate an AlertDialog.Builder with its constructor
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());


        //Get the Layout inflater
        //LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());

        //Create Dialog
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());

        //Diable title
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
        // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
        // builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_register, null));
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.login_forgetpassword);

        // Transparency
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

        // 3. Get the AlertDialog from create()
        //return builder.create();
        return dialog;
    }
```

**Error:**

```
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method openForgetPasswordSend(View) in the activity class android.view.ContextThemeWrapper for onClick handler on view class android.widget.TextView with id 'login_email_tvForgetPassword'
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4209)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5156)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20755)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: openForgetPasswordSend [class android.view.View]
            at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:665)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4202)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5156)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20755)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

I appreciated your help!